# Possible to apply a shared resources file for multi-module gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, logback

I want a global logback xml config file shared across my multi-module gradle project.

I have my `logback.xml` file inside of a `utilities` module under *resources*. In my gradle at the root under the `subprojects` block I have added the following:

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs += "utilities"
            }
        }
    }
```

I was interpreting this as a file copy, essentially, to place the resources contents of utilities into each subproject. The logger isn't recognizing this. What's the best way to share this config across all subprojects?

Comment: How about just putting it in a separate project and make a normal dependency on that from all the projects that need it? That's what I have done in the past. (The configuration file will end up in a jar file, which is otherwise empty.) Other than that, adding the folder to resources should work too - just be sure the relative reference is correct in each sub-project.

Answer (score 0):

Given I don't know of a way to do this with some in-built magic, I'd probably put the logback.xml into a `/static` content directory, next to the root `build.gradle`, and have gradle copy it to all relevant `build/.../resources` directories at build time.

If you look at the image below, which represents the build lifecycle phases of gradle, you could insert the task to do this after `processResources` (or `processTestResources`) and before `classes`:

[image]

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

You'll probably also need to find/use the `/build` directory, dynamically, via some in-built gradle reference, and add this task to the root `build.gradle` script.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I did the following in my root.gradle subprojects block.

```
    if (name != "utilities") {
        sourceSets {
            data {
                resources {
                    // Universal logback config for all sub-modules
                    srcDir "${project(':utilities').projectDir}/src/main/resources"
                    include "logback.xml"
                }
            }
            main {
                resources {
                    srcDirs += [data.resources]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```